# Create custom Grails Tag Lib the generates code

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, taglib

Is there any documentation regarding how to create a custom grails tag that generated groovy code similar to "<g:if>" and "<g:else>"?

Using the normal grails taglib, I'm able to generate html or raw output, but I'm looking to output code that can be interpreted similar to how the if and else tags work.

Here's a sample of the Grails source code for the "if" tag:

```
@Override
protected void outputStartTag(String envExpression, String testExpression) {
    out.print("if(");
    out.print(envExpression);
    out.print(" && ");
    out.print(testExpression);
    out.println(") {");
}
```

How can I do something similar in my own taglib prefix.

Example:

```
<mine:doSomethingCool key="foo">This text is conditionally shown</mine:doSomethingCool>
```

In addition to hiding complex logic, I would like this ability so I can use the <g:else> tag after my custom tag.

In general, I would like another tool in my toolbox in addition to the current taglib format.

Comment: Could you provide little more detail of what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question to be a little more specific.

Comment: if you want the `g:if` tag on steroids, extend the original `if` tag

Comment: @injecteer I could create my own class and extend from GroovyIfTag, but how would grails recognize my changes? How do I name my tag? How do I specify my namespace?

Comment: @injecteer I just found the GrailsTagRegistry but I think that puts me in the "g:" namespace. This would suffice, but I would prefer my own.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I was using <% LoggingService.log("something ${somevar}") %> and I thought custom tags would generate that code for me just like g:if but it does not happen - so I am puzzled how it has happened for g:if. Finding it difficult to find the code on github for the closures where the if tag does it job - just to see if I am missing a trick here.

Answer (score 1):

If for example you only want to render the conditional text when `key == 'foo'`, you could do that like this:

```
class SomethingTagLib {

    static namespace = "ns"

    def doSomethingCool = { attrs, body ->
        if (attrs.key == 'foo') {
            out << body()
        }
    }
}
```

You could then use this tag like so:

```
<ns:doSomethingCool key="foo">This text is conditionally shown<ns:doSomethingCool>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm familiar with how to create taglibs in this fashion. I'm looking for the more complex version. I've updated my question to hopefully reflect this.